# On screen keyboard interaction with UAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have created a winforms onscreen keyboard in C# with visual studio however this will not work when the UAC (User Account Control) window comes up so an administrator is unable to use their login details for specific troubleshooting areas.

I have tried using the following which work everywhere but none will work with the UAC window, these do not type anything;

SendKeys 
user32.dll keybd_event function 
InputSimulator

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running your app on Windows 10? If so have you tried TabTip? Have a look at https://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2016/05/Controlling-the-Windows-10-On-Screen-keyboard-from-a-Net-Windows-Forms-application.aspx

Comment: That would be a major security hole if Windows allowed for software to "send keys" to a UAC prompt.

Comment: Yes this is being ran on Windows 10. We are currently using TabTip on tablets however we require a custom keyboard that has additional functions for use with our applications which is working fine but the only issue is being able to type in the UAC for our Admins when physically at the tablet (without an external keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

The UAC prompt will not open on the current desktop, but in the brand-new Secure Desktop, it will suspend any currently open desktop.
It is intentional, because the program is not allowed to interact with this dialog box.

There is one exception: "Trusted SYSTEM processes can run on a secure desktop", so you can refer to the following materials.
[Ease of Access registry details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/ease-of-access---assistive-technology-registration?redirectedfrom=MSDN#ease-of-access-registry-details)
[UI Automation Security Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-security-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Do put the salient details from the link in your answer. Linking should only be for supporting evidence.